# How to pass query parameter to api using map method and concatenate every json response to setState in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In below code i am calling api by passing query parameter by map method and i want to concatenate the resulted json of each query and update the state.

But here i am facing problem that setState is updated with the any one of returned json.

```
import React from 'react';

const api_key = "key";

class card extends React.Component {
    state = {
        articles: [],
        parameter: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    };

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        this.state.newsPaper.map(async (querypara) => {
            const requstone = await fetch(`https:someapisources=${querypara}&apiKey=${api_key}`);
            const dataone = await requstone.json();

            this.setState({
                articles: dataone.articles
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    {this.state.articles.map((article, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={index}>
                                <div>
                                    <img src={article.urlToImage} alt="Avatar" />
                                    <div>
                                        <h4><b>{article.title}</b></h4>
                                        <p>
                                            {article.description}
                                        </p>
                                        <section>
                                            <div>
                                                <span>Source:</span>
                                                 <span>{article.source.name}</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </section>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default card;
```

**I want to add each response json and render it by setting the state how can i do that**

Below is the sample json response.

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "totalResults": 8,
    "articles": [{
            "source": {
                "id": "recode",
                "name": "Recode"
            },
            "author": "Recode Staff",
            "title": "title",
            "description": "Something",
            "url": "url",
            "urlToImage": "image url.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-11-26T13:23:06Z",
            "content": "some content"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "recode",
                "name": "Recode"
            },
            "author": "Recode Staff",
            "title": "title",
            "description": "Something",
            "url": "url",
            "urlToImage": "image url.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2018-11-26T13:23:06Z",
            "content": "some content"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then the only adjustment needed here is to update your `setState()` logic so that you append `articles` from your response to the `articles` array in your state:

```
this.state.newsPaper.map(async (querypara) => {

    const requstone = await fetch(`https:someapisources=${querypara}&apiKey=${api_key}`);
    const dataone = await requstone.json();

    // Concatenate articles from response (dataone) to array in state
    this.setState({
        articles: this.state.articles.concat(dataone.articles)
    });
}
```